# Cannot create survival object: error "Time variable is not numeric"

Tags: r, object, numeric

I try to create a survival object using this command.

```
Surv(date1, date2, event=status)
```

It resulted in error "Time variable is not numeric".
Note that class of "date1" and "date2" is Date.

Do I need to coerce Date objects into numeric before creating survival objects?
I think this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What programming language? What is `survival`?

Answer (score 3):

The Time variable must be numeric for the survival function to work or in your case you could do something like:
`Surv(as.numeric(date2 - date1), event=status)`